# Responsive images with srcset and sizes

Tags: html, responsive-images

I have responsive images with `picture` tag and want to use `srcset` and `sizes`.
I've noticed that browser serves wrong img src.
Here is codepen and html:

https://codepen.io/piernik/pen/YzgzrJX

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img width="516" height="290" src="https://via.placeholder.com/516x290/ffa/000?text=loaded:%20516%20px" class="img-fluid rounded" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1296x730/ffa/000?text=loaded:%201296%20px 1296w, https://via.placeholder.com/1116x628/ffa/000?text=loaded:%201116%20px 1116w, https://via.placeholder.com/951x535/ffa/000?text=loaded:%20951%20px 951w, https://via.placeholder.com/696x392/ffa/000?text=loaded:%20696%20px 696w, https://via.placeholder.com/516x290/ffa/000?text=loaded:%20516%20px 516w" sizes="400px"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

As `sizes` attribute I put `400px`. It means that it should take image that has 400px width. But it takes the one with 696 pixels. Why?

[image]

Comment: Yes and I think it is a browser bug, not feature. Thanks.